# DAX count number of rows between transaction types

Tags: count, dax

I have a calculated table that returns each purchase and sale transaction by stock ticker by date.

Then I created a helper column that returns whether each row relates to a "Purchase" transaction, a "Sale" transaction, or to both ("Purchase/Sale").

```
ADDCOLUMNS( 
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( 
        dAssets[Ticker], 
        dDates[Date], 
        "Purchased", [Shares purchased], 
        "Sold", [Shares sold], 
        "Balance", [Shares balance] 
    ), 
    "Transaction", SWITCH( 
        TRUE(), 
        [Purchased] <> BLANK() && [Sold] = BLANK(), "Purchase", 
        [Purchased] = BLANK() && [Sold] <> BLANK(), "Sale", 
        [Purchased] <> BLANK() && [Sold] <> BLANK(), "Purchase/Sale" 
    ) 
)
```

What I need is a **calculated column** that indicates how many rows (NEGATIVE) above each "Sale" row the last "Purchase" sale row had taken place.

- Obviously, in case a row refers to a "Purchase" transaction then return "null/blank".
- And for those rows that refer to dates on which both "Purchase" and "Sale" took place then return ZERO.
- One requirement must be followed: making sure such row count takes place within each group of tickers.

Below is a sample of the table produced by the above code and the last column **"Row diff. count"** in **bold** was manually added to refer to the desired calculated column output.

| Ticker | Date | Purchased | Sold | Balance | Transaction | Row diff. count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IRBR3 | 1/26/2021 | 4 |  | 4 | Purchase |  |
| IRBR3 | 3/24/2021 |  | 4 | 0 | Sale | **-1** |
| IRBR3 | 6/30/2021 | 5 |  | 5 | Purchase |  |
| IRBR3 | 8/18/2021 | 6 |  | 11 | Purchase |  |
| IRBR3 | 9/22/2021 | 6 | 5 | 12 | Purchase/Sale | **0** |
| IRBR3 | 11/18/2021 | 7 | 6 | 13 | Purchase/Sale | **0** |
| IRBR3 | 12/27/2021 |  | 6 | 7 | Sale | **-1** |
| IRBR3 | 3/28/2022 |  | 7 | 0 | Sale | **-2** |
| IRBR3 | 6/24/2022 | 13 |  | 13 | Purchase |  |
| IRBR3 | 8/11/2022 |  | 13 | 0 | Sale | **-1** |
| IRBR3 | 8/30/2022 | 18 |  | 18 | Purchase |  |
| IRBR3 | 12/22/2022 |  | 18 | 0 | Sale | **-1** |
| IRBR3 | 2/28/2023 | 52 |  | 52 | Purchase |  |
| IRBR3 | 5/2/2023 |  | 52 | 0 | Sale | **-1** |
| ITSA4 | 1/22/2021 | 119 |  | 119 | Purchase |  |
| ITSA4 | 6/7/2021 |  | 119 | 0 | Sale | **-1** |
| ITSA4 | 7/1/2021 | 114 |  | 114 | Purchase |  |
| ITSA4 | 8/3/2021 |  | 114 | 0 | Sale | **-1** |

This seems simple but I just can't get a way to make it work...

Right out of the gate I get the error "the column 'Transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression" when trying to generate a calculated column with the Date of the last "Purchase" transaction prior to each respective "Sale".

```
VAR Tbl = 
    ADDCOLUMNS( 
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( 
            dAssets[Ticker], 
            dDates[Date], 
            "Purchased", [Shares purchased], 
            "Sold", [Shares sold], 
            "Balance", [Shares balance] 
        ), 
        "Transaction", SWITCH( 
            TRUE(), 
            [Purchased] <> BLANK() && [Sold] = BLANK(), "Purchase", 
            [Purchased] = BLANK() && [Sold] <> BLANK(), "Sale", 
            [Purchased] <> BLANK() && [Sold] <> BLANK(), "Purchase/Sale" 
        ) 
    )
RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        Tbl, 
        "Last Purchase Date", 
        VAR Ticker_Ref = dAssets[Ticker]
        VAR Date_Ref = MAX( dDates[Date] )
        RETURN
        CALCULATE( 
            MAXX( 
                dDates, 
                dDates[Date] 
            ), 
            dAssets[Ticker] = Ticker_Ref, 
            dDates[Date] <= Date_Ref, 
            [Transaction] = "Purchase" || [Transaction] = "Purchase/Sale" 
        )
    )
```